# How to /execute from nearest gold block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to `/execute` a command from the nearest gold block to a command block within a certain range. Is this possible and how can I do it?

Comment: I don't think this is directly possible, but you could just hide an entity in it depending on the situation

Comment: What sort of command are you planning on running?

Answer (score -1):

Does [`/execute positioned`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/execute#positioned) do what you want?

e.g. for a gold block at `X=0 Y=64 Z=0`:

```
execute positioned 0 64 0 run <command>
```

Comment: I think the asker means that he doesn't know where the gold block would be